# Typescript: declare return type to be dependent on argument value?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function call:

```
this.get('barcode').scan();
```

Is it possible to define the get function in a way that the return type is determined by the value of the function argument. In my case 'get' returns the Barcode class if called with 'barcode' and the Mqtt class if called with 'mqtt'.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1295

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use *overload on strings* to do this. Example:

```
interface BarcodeScanner { scan(): number; }
interface Accelerometer { getAcceleration(): number; }

class MyClass {
    get(name: 'accelerometer'): Accelerometer;
    get(name: 'barcode'): BarcodeScanner;
    get(name: string): any; // Fallback string signature
    get(name: string): any { // Implementation signature, not visible
        /* ... */
        return undefined;
    }

    something() {
        let x = this.get('barcode');
        x.scan(); // OK
        let y = this.get('accelerometer');
        y.getAcceleration(); // OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to statically determine a type in function of a (dynamic) string. But [generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics) are made for these cases.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    public get<T>(type: string): T {
        // ...
    }
    public anotherMethod() {
        this.get<Barcode>('barcode').scan();
    }
}
```

---

I'm not sure to understand the problem with Ember, but if the method `get` is dynamically inserted in the object, then maybe a solution like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public get: function<T> (type: string): T; // this is just a static declaration, there is no generated JS code here

    public anotherMethod() {
        this.get<Barcode>('barcode').scan();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to retrofit the type declaration to an existing  JavaScript library.

Comment: So, you can describe the type `Barcode` from the existing JavaScript library [with the keyword `declare`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) or with an interface.

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood the problem. The  problem is that I havent figured out  to make TypeScript accept the get declaration (I get Property 'get' is missing in type). Which is true since it comes from the Ember Framework.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use [the ember definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ember)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of Typescript 3.2 you can use conditional types to do the trick:

```js
const get = <T extends "barcode" | "mqtt">(s: T) =>
    s === "barcode" ?
        <T extends "barcode" ? {scan: () => string} : {pan: () => string}>{scan: () => "we are scanning"} :
        <T extends "barcode" ? {scan: () => string} : {pan: () => string}>{pan: () => "we are panning"}

get("barcode").scan() // OK
get("mqtt").pan()     // OK
get("barcode").pan() // Error
```

Note: I did not succeed in moving the casts to the function's return type - this will have to be put in another question for the real experts.

Comment: Asked a question about the casts here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55059436/2684980