# Variable return types based on string literal type argument

Tags: typescript

Can I have variable return type based on the value of a string literal type argument in TypeScript 1.8 or 2.0?

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange" 
function doSomething(foo : Fruit) : string | string[] {
    if (foo == "apple") return "hello";
    else return ["hello","world"];
}

var test : string[] = doSomething("orange");
```

> Error: TS2322: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type
>   'string[]'.

Comment: `test` variable type should be `string[]|string`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I disagree. If passing `"orange"` as the argument to `doSomething` always yields a `string[]`, then it is correct for `test` to have that type as well. You need to use [overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39743710/2788872).

Comment: @JohnWhite `doSomething` signature clearly states that the return type is   `string[]|string` which is not the case with overloading where you just specifying return type according to specific input

Comment: @AlekseyL. I guess it's really a matter of pespective. However, `"orange" => string[]` is the signature that actually represents the runtime behaviour, and not `"orange" => string | string[]`.

Comment: You could use conditional types, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059318/2684980

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, you can use overload signatures to achieve exactly what you want:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange"

function doSomething(foo: "apple"): string;
function doSomething(foo: "orange"): string[];
function doSomething(foo: Fruit): string | string[]
{
    if (foo == "apple") return "hello";
    else return ["hello", "world"];
}

let orange: string[] = doSomething("orange");
let apple: string = doSomething("apple");
```

Trying to assign `doSomething("apple")` to `orange` would yield a compile-time type-error:

```
let orange: string[] = doSomething("apple");
 // ^^^^^^
 // type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
```

[Live demo on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiAoBqFqAMwWoGNglzqoAE3IBlcgFsIwABZI6ACjblyALiy4CRAJRqAzsDhzaAbmasO3XvyGiJU2QqWqKVOtr0GjAbQC6p1uycPHwCwmKSMkaKymrwyMA6UPqGdKRJnnS+ZiwA3tkBUEhsUNHk6Bg4eISYWlBwUghwApjSEPj45Jj+BSxtutD1wI0CXi1tHZgANFgA7pT4gph++QC++QyEqJQ09B4ptL7oNuH2UZjbbjWmm1AahHtGR2F2kQqVmldMAPRfUAAqrSg1AgAA9UNhdLokLRqJJqKhdNJyAgFlAAEbQGhQCBwOCUAB0GykUAu9AATA9Mj4nrYIg5aPJ3tUtKYgA)

It is important to note that determining which overload signature was used must always be done in the function implementation manually, and the function implementation must [support all overload signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35552201/2788872).

There are no separate implementations per overload in TypeScript as there are in, say, C#. As such, I find it a good practice to reinforce TypeScript type-checks at runtime, for example:

```
switch (foo) {
    case "apple":
        return "hello";
    case "orange":
        return ["hello", "world"];
    default:
        throw new TypeError("Invalid string value.");
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if this was true, but unless I'm mistaken it's not. Typescript supports overloading methods with signatures having different numbers of parameters, but not signatures with the same number parameters of different type. String literal types are simply strings when compiled to JS, so how could your three `doSomething()` functions be differentiated?

Comment: @drewmoore *"how could your three doSomething() functions be differentiated?"* -- In this case, with a value check, obviously. It might also be a good idea to throw a `TypeError` here if `foo` is not of any of the supported values.

Comment: There are compiler errors in your demo :) Those value checks can only be done at runtime, not compile time - which is when TS type safety is enforced

Comment: @drewmoore That is, the last two assigments are there to demonstrate that you cannot assign `doSomething("apple")` to `string[]`.

Comment: Ah, I'll be damned. I was hoping you'd be right :) This is new as of TS 2.0 - and hooray for it. I already +1'd, but OP - **this is the correct answer for TS >= 2.0.0**

Comment: I believe this is a much better answer than my accepted answer. Please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: How do you do this with arrow functions?

Answer (score 4):

I have a better approach. use a generic which is then used as the type of the argument (So then you won't need to pass the generic manually and typescript will infer it automatically). Then you can use that type and choose the correct return type.

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange';
function doSomething<P extends Fruit>(foo: P): ({ apple: string; orange: string[] })[P] {
  if (foo === 'apple') return 'hello';
  return ['hello','world];
}
const x: string = doSomething('apple');
const y: string[] = doSomething('orange');
```

This way you can change the return type of your function based on the argument passed automatically.

Comment: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '{ apple: string; orange: string[]; }[P]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string & string[]'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigcgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiBuAWACgAzBagY2CXOqgATcgGVyAWwjAAFkjoAeAApQIAD2ARqggM6xEKAHwAKNuXIAuKIoCUlowG8ouAhEvbgcObQZRKNem4eXgDaALpQAL7WwYrh9qxQUEhsUCZm6GgYOHiEmNZQcFIIcAKY0hD4+OSYzCyJhcDFAsFlFVWYADSYAO6U+IKhtRGsXPzuUKqBnnToQqISUrJ0RtkuebWj1OMgUyHhGMJikjJeK350RNYMQA

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to test your `test` variable with `instanceof`. Typescript will then limit the type.

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange" 
function doSomething(foo: Fruit): string | string[] {
    if (foo == "apple") return "hello";
    else return ["hello","world"]
}

// here the type is still inferred as: string | string[]
var test = doSomething("orange");

if (test instanceof String) {
    // TypeScript knows test is type: string
    doSomethingWithString(test);
} else {
    // TypeScript knows test is type: string[]
    doSomethingWithStringArray(test);
}

function doSomethingWithString(input: string) {}
function doSomethingWithStringArray(input: string[]) {}
```

**UPDATE**

You may just want to make the method generic instead.

```
function doSomething<T>(foo: Fruit): T {
    if (foo == "apple") return "hello";
    else return ["hello","world"]
}

var test1 = doSomething<string>("apple");
var test2 = doSomething<string[]>("orange");
```

Or another option would be to invert the flow to something like this:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange" 
function doSomething(foo: Fruit): void {
    if (foo == "apple") 
        doSomthingWithString("hello");
    else 
        doSomethingWithStringArray(["hello","world"]);
}

function doSomethingWithString(input: string) {}
function doSomethingWithStringArray(input: string[]) {}
```

**UPDATE**

Actually I believe **John White**'s is a much better answer.

Comment: The generic will do in my case. The other alternatives are too cumbersome for my usecase. Thanks

Comment: Actually I believe @john-white 's answer is a much better answer to your specific question. Please mark his answer as the correct one.