# Typescript workaround to return narrowed types

Tags: typescript

In typescipt, I need a way for a function to, given an argument of a particular type, return an object of a type that is related to the type of the argument.

See below for an example. I need a way to make 'const response = ...' more narrowly typed than it is.

The example below is for having requests of particular types linked to responses that are relevant only to the requests given. For example, given a request that finds information about a user, we want to have a the response that contains their name and age. But when given a request that finds information about a car, we want to have a response with information about the make and the miles of the car. We will only ever want to use the 'user' response for the 'user' request and similar for 'car'.

```
class RequestBase {
}

class ResponseBase {
}

interface IFindUserReq {
    user_id :string
}
class FindUserRequest implements IFindUserReq {
    user_id :string
    constructor(user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id
    }
}

interface IFindUserRes {
    name :string
    age  :number
}
class FindUserResponse implements IFindUserRes {
    name :string
    age  :number
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

interface IFindCarReq {
    car_id :number
}
class FindCarRequest implements IFindCarReq {
    car_id :number 
    constructor(car_id) {
        this.car_id = car_id
    }
}

interface IFindCarRes {
    make :string
    miles :number
}
class FindCarResponse implements IFindCarRes {
    make :string
    miles  :number
    constructor(make, miles) {
        this.make = make;
        this.miles = miles;
    }
}

const request = new FindUserRequest("foo")
const response = performRequest(request) // the type here is 'RequestBase | undefined'. Is there any way to automatically narrow it to be FindCarResponse?

function performRequest(req :RequestBase) : RequestBase | undefined {
    if (req instanceof FindUserRequest) {
        return new FindUserResponse("foo", 23) // hard coded example for convenience
    } else if (req instanceof FindCarRequest) {
        return new FindCarResponse("toyota", 10000)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE : Solution 1**
Inspired by [Variable return types based on string literal type argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700093/variable-return-types-based-on-string-literal-type-argument)

One approach is to overload the 'performRequest' signature like so:

```
function performRequest(req :FindCarRequest) : FindCarResponse 
function performRequest(req :FindUserRequest) : FindUserResponse
function performRequest(req :RequestBase) : ResponseBase | undefined   {
    if (req instanceof FindUserRequest) {
        return new FindUserResponse("foo", 23) // hard coded example for convenience
    } else if (req instanceof FindCarRequest) {
        return new FindCarResponse("toyota", 10000)
    }
}
```

However, I would really like for the library that maintains the request and response types to not have to alter the signature of the function in the application that is using the request and response types (performRequest). So I'd still like to hear other solutions.

**UPDATE Solution 2**
Thanks for Gerrit Birkeland from TS Gitter channel for this:

```
class RequestBase {
    _responseType : ResponseBase
}

class ResponseBase {
}

interface IFindUserReq {
    user_id :string
}
class FindUserRequest extends RequestBase implements IFindUserReq {
    _responseType :FindUserResponse
    user_id :string
    constructor(user_id) {
        super()
        this.user_id = user_id
    }
}

interface IFindUserRes {
    name :string
    age  :number
}
class FindUserResponse extends ResponseBase implements IFindUserRes {
    name :string
    age  :number
    constructor(name, age) {
        super()
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

interface IFindCarReq {
    car_id :number
}
class FindCarRequest extends RequestBase implements IFindCarReq {
    _responseType :FindCarResponse
    car_id :number 
    constructor(car_id) {
        super()
        this.car_id = car_id
    }
}

interface IFindCarRes {
    make :string
    miles :number
}
class FindCarResponse extends ResponseBase implements IFindCarRes {
    make :string
    miles  :number
    constructor(make, miles) {
        super()
        this.make = make;
        this.miles = miles;
    }
}

const request = new FindUserRequest("foo")
const response = performRequest<FindUserRequest>(request) // the type of response here is ResponseBase, not sure why it's not narrowed 

function performRequest< T extends RequestBase>(req :T) :T["_responseType"]    {

    if (req instanceof FindUserRequest) {
        return new FindUserResponse("foo", 23) // hard coded example for convenience
    } else if (req instanceof FindCarRequest) {
        return new FindCarResponse("toyota", 10000)
    } else {
        return new ResponseBase()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (mostly) achieve the desired effect by adding a property to the `RequestBase` class. This property doesn't need to be used for anything, but it does need to exist.

(Copied from my gitter message)

```ts
class RequestBase {
  _responseType: ResponseBase
}

class ResponseBase {}

class FindUserRequest implements RequestBase {
  _responseType: FindUserResponse
  user_id: string
  constructor(user_id: string) {
    this.user_id = user_id
  }
}

class FindUserResponse {
  name: string
  age: number
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const request = new FindUserRequest("foo")
const response = performRequest(request) // FindUserResponse | undefined

function performRequest<T extends RequestBase>(req: T): T["_responseType"] | undefined {
  if (req instanceof FindUserRequest) {
    return new FindUserResponse("foo", 23)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `RequestBase` to be generic you can add a generic type argument representing the response type. You can then use this to return the response type.

```
class RequestBase<TResponse> {
    performRequest() : TResponse {
        return null; // Dummy, could invoke the actual performRequest
    }
}
class FindCarRequest extends RequestBase<FindCarResponse> {
    constructor(public car_id: number) {
        super();
    }
}
class FindCarResponse {
    constructor(public make: string, public miles: number) {
    }
}

const request = new FindCarRequest(100)
const response = request.performRequest() // Will be typed as FindCarResponse
```

**Note** Unfortunately, keeping the `performRequest` function as an external function is not an option as type inference is not smart enough to get the generic type parameter from the base type:

```
function performRequest<T>(req: RequestBase<T>):T {
    return null; // Dummy
}

const request = new FindCarRequest(100)
const response = performRequest(request) // Will be typed as {} although I would have expected this to be FindCarResponse

const request2 = new RequestBase<FindCarResponse>()
const response2 = performRequest(request) // Will be typed as FindCarResponse
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together - the problem is that there is a particular interface we want in the return type, to link to a particular interface for the request type. While the particular interface can be made to be generic, there doesn't seem to be a way, using the approach you've suggested, to obtain one particular interface from another.