# TypeScript: function return type based on argument, without overloading

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to return a function's type based on an argument?

I saw [Variable return types based on string literal type argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700093/variable-return-types-based-on-string-literal-type-argument), but it uses overloading. Here, I have 100+ types, so I do not want to do overloading.

```
interface Registry {
    A: number,
    B: string,
    C: boolean,
    // ... 100 more types like this
}

function createType<T = Registry[typeof myType]>(myType: keyof Registry, value: any): T {
    // do some magic
    // ...
    return value;
}

const a = createType('A', 2); // Expected type: number. Actual: error above
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQObAM5igT2QG8AoZc5AQQC5kQBXAWwCNoAaMigIVtylAwcKyAMK1mAewkAbCHBAkAviRIx6IBGGASQyBFDmQAKvgAOEADxHkAXjSYcefAG0wZiBJjI35gLoA+AAofCFoAawh8T3ssPnw2ZAA3OGl6UOR5fABKWmtSYQMweihdZNSIAG4lFQQdXAzbPQM4Y3dAgHJKdoSAJiyqoA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it, but you will need a type parameter to capture the argument passed in. With this new type parameter you can index into your `Registry` to get the type you want:

```
interface Registry {
    A: number,
    B: string,
    C: boolean
}

function createType<K extends keyof Registry>(type: K, value: Registry[K]): Registry[K] {
    return value;
}

const a = createType('A', 2); // ok 
const b = createType('B', 2); // err
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot

Comment: I got a similar question. How would you do it for an optional parameter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259852/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-optional-parameter-presence-without-usi