# Typescript function return type based on optional parameter presence without using function overloads

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings, optional-parameters

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgmgBQKIH0CMUC8UBE9no4BQoksiqATFrvlcSeNAMIDyAcgCICSM3HNHGy69+7BgDMArgDsAxsACWAexlQJy5QAo5qgCaKlqgPwAuKMJ58OASnN10UAD7kC1AN5Eo3qIolQdfUMVGRsoTx9IqAAnCGApaLU8CkIAbi8fAF8M7wgAGwBnaAio71j4xNoUyhx0yOzsol0ZAuAoAoALZSk8vQAhCBgmR2wNbSEOKzEcG1TIgHp5qCQAJRXWFfsACW4AZSg9qD6kbnYAcWWANQBBABkAVWuYJE4oa-379jFXJHNkgjQOGcVTcxGarXaXR6-UGw2oo00WlmpRR3kWyzWG22h0Ox1OFyQNweTxebw+XwEdD+DkBwP+9CIRHmACooABiDmcrncnm8vm8qDM+ZM1lc2A7faHJDvOCwVhQTjygDqvC2UFYl1Wt1Y104+zFQpF7P5JtNZsFwqI0nkRjUYxQygAbhBonllABDPQQPRI+zVK2yBQhdSaB3O10er0+5oGW1-SyiDgzP0AgM24P2p0ut2e72BGSxkJmXAJ6ziOw-RwuBweHK+fz5wuqMIlUrlBJJGm1OvZSL5IrhOuRduVekoGp1LJERrgtpZiO5vQoTrdXoDIaQEYh5Rh7ORvMTERlmZzNFLXb3ZjMJC7XbYyX7GlNVQQ+c5qPLqFr2Gb+Hb3cLlGSKnqiCznpe163veByPtUQA)

My goal here is to return a different type based on the presence of a optional `condition: "CONDITION"` parameter. And I'm trying to accomplish this without resorting to overloads.

```
type TYPE_1 = "TYPE_1"
type TYPE_2 = "TYPE_2"

type CONDITION = "CONDITION"

function foo(condition?: CONDITION): TYPE_1 | TYPE_2 {
    if (condition) {
        return "TYPE_1";
    }
    else {
        return "TYPE_2";
    }
}

const shouldBeType_1 = foo("CONDITION");    // ERROR: THIS IS BEING EVALUATED AS UNION TYPE: "TYPE_1" | "TYPE_2"
const shouldBeType_2 = foo();               // ERROR: THIS IS BEING EVALUATED AS UNION TYPE: "TYPE_1" | "TYPE_2"
```

This is easy to accomplish with overloads:

```
/* ########################################### */
/* #### THIS IS EASY TO DO WITH OVERLOADS #### */
/* ########################################### */

function foo_overloaded(): TYPE_2
function foo_overloaded(condition: "CONDITION"): TYPE_1
function foo_overloaded(condition?: "CONDITION"): TYPE_1 | TYPE_2 {
    if (condition) {
        return "TYPE_1";
    }
    else {
        return "TYPE_2";
    }
}

const overloaded_shouldBeType_1 = foo_overloaded("CONDITION");   // SUCCESS: THIS IS TYPE_1
const overloaded_shouldBeType_2 = foo_overloaded();              // SUCCESS: THIS IS TYPE_2
```

What is the proper way of doing it without overloads? Or am I over complicating it and overloading is simply the way to go in this situation?

Also there is this question here on SO: [TypeScript: function return type based on argument, without overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199372/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-argument-without-overloading)

It suggests that an interface should be used as a map to the return type, like:

```
interface Registry {
    A: number,
    B: string,
    C: boolean
}

function createType<K extends keyof Registry>(type: K, value: Registry[K]): Registry[K] {
    return value;
}
```

But I can't do that, because `condition` is either `"CONDITION" | undefined`. So how can I map the `undefined` type? I also tried doing that with conditional type. Something like:

```
type RETURN_TYPE<T extends undefined | "CONDITION"> = T extends "CONDITION" ? TYPE_1 : TYPE_2;
```

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say you would go with overloaded functions in this case, you can solve this partly with the following:

```
function foo<T extends CONDITION | undefined>(condition?: T): T extends CONDITION ? TYPE_1 : TYPE_2 {
    if (condition) {
        //`as any` is intentional here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable
        return "TYPE_1" as any;
    } else {
        return "TYPE_2" as any;
    }
}
```

With this, the following works fine:

```
const shouldBeType_1 = foo("CONDITION") // It is TYPE_1;
```

But when you don't pass any params it would not work:

```
const shouldBeType_2 = foo(); // It is TYPE_1 | TYPE_2
```

Of course if you pass undefined directly, it works correctly:

```
const shouldBeType_2 = foo(undefined); // It is TYPE_2;
```

---

So long stroy short, right now, the cleanest approach for your problem, is to use function overloading.

---

**EDIT**
As it has been pointed out if I add a default parameter for the generic type, this would work with omitted param as well.

```
function foo<T extends CONDITION | undefined = undefined>(condition?: T): T extends CONDITION ? TYPE_1 : TYPE_2 {
    if (condition) {
        return "TYPE_1" as any;
    } else {
        return "TYPE_2" as any;
    }
}

// Both work:
const shouldBeType_1 = foo("CONDITION") // It is TYPE_1;
const shouldBeType_2 = foo(); // It is TYPE_2;
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I'm always hesitating when it comes to overloading cause I think the code becomes too verbose, but I guess this is a good use for it. I'll wait a few days to see if somebody comes up with some new idea, though.

Comment: I see your point, but IMO in this situation that is the best approach.

Comment: You can fix the `undefined` case by setting a default value for `T`. i.e. `<T extends CONDITION | undefined = undefined>`. Then the return types will all be as desired.

Comment: Good point @ccarton, I have updated my answer including your fix.

Comment: But in that case the `any` assertion is still necessary?

Comment: Sadly yes, that is a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable

Comment: It does work as intended when you add the `= undefined`. But the  `any` assertions are terrible to look at. If this is the only option, I'd rather go with overloads. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Just adding the link for the TS issue about the `any` assertion being necessary on conditional return types. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-363265172