# How to dissect union types

Tags: typescript

```js
function fetchX(url:string){
 switch(url){
   case '/api/user':
     return {name:"Jack"} // User type
   case '/api/money':
     return {amonth:100} // Money type
}
}
```

so when I use it to get one of them return value is union  `User | Money` .

Documentation suggests using `typeof`, `if( typeof res == 'string' )`. But they didnt think of type system beyond primitives.

How can I get right type based on string I pass?

Comment: It's called ``Union Type Narrowing``

Comment: Could you [edit] to show a [mre] of the actual problem you're having?  What specifically can't you do?  There's no `res` in your example and you didn't define `User` or `Money` for us, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Possibly you're just looking for `if ("amonth" in res)` (whatever "amonth" is) but I can't tell without a [mre].

Comment: Do you mean how does the _caller_ know which they're getting, in which case maybe https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I've defined two overloads and worked. Please copy comment as answer, so I can close

Comment: In that case it's a dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39700093/3001761