# Typescript conditional return type based on string argument

Tags: typescript, generics

When using union of string literals as input argument, what would it take to **remove the casts and put the type into the function header**:

```js
const get = <T extends "barcode" | "mqtt">(s: T) =>
    s === "barcode" ?
        <T extends "barcode" ? {scan: () => string} : {pan: () => string}>{scan: () => "we are scanning"} :
        <T extends "barcode" ? {scan: () => string} : {pan: () => string}>{pan: () => "we are panning"}

get("barcode").scan() // OK
get("mqtt").pan()     // OK
get("barcode").pan() // Error
```

I ran into this trying to answer someone else's question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059318/2684980.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The cleanest solution is such cases (although not any more type safe than the type assertions) is to use overloads instead. You can use conditional types in the public signature, and a simple union in the implementation signature. You will need to switch to a function declaration as function expressions (arrow or regular) don't easily suport overloads:

```
function get<T extends "barcode" | "mqtt">(s: T): T extends "barcode" ? { scan: () => string } : { pan: () => string }
function get(s: "barcode" | "mqtt"): { scan: () => string } | { pan: () => string } {
    return s === "barcode" ?
        { scan: () => "we are scanning" } :
        { pan: () => "we are panning" }
}

get("barcode").scan() // OK
get("mqtt").pan()     // OK
get("barcode").pan() // Error
```

Comment: This would be better, although not exactly what I was hoping for.  Do you have to specify the return type in the implementation?

Comment: @JørgenTvedt I think you can get away with removing it from the implementation. You will get an error id the conditional branches are not in the returned union

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand why my code does not work without the casts, that's why I hesitate to mark this as the answer.

Comment: @JørgenTvedt because Typescript does not reason about conditional types that contain unresolved type parameters. Except for very limited circumstances, it will just check for an exact type match.

Comment: Ok, so if I move the conditional type thing to the return type of my function - typescript cannot auto-cast the or-ish expression. In my head - the return of the type guard should not be a union type at all, but a conditional type.  Would not that be more correct?

Comment: @JørgenTvedt Typescript does not take flow analysis to this level. Flow analysis will impact just the types of the variables inside the guarded block. It will not help the compiler infer any conditional types.